# Restrict the data after 3rd node in SAPUI5 TreeTable

Tags: sapui5

In treeTable, I don't want to show the data after 3rd node i.e. **connList** data in first column (in tree). I can't remove node from JSON as I have to use it for another column. Is it possible without removing connList node from json. Please suggest me solution if any. Thanks in Avance!

createContent : function(oController) {

**Sample JSON with *connList* node -**

```
    var response={"name": "Root", "checked": "Checked",
            "dataList": [
                {"name": "Parent1",
                    "exList": [
                        {"name": "SubParent1",
                            "sysList": [{"name": "Child1", "externalId": "External 1",
                                "connList": [ {"id":1, "name": "conn1" },
                                    {"id":2, "name": "conn2" },
                                    {"id":3, "name": "conn3"}
                                ]
                            },
                                {"name": "Child2", "externalId": "External 2" }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {"name": "Parent2",
                    "exList": [
                        {"name": "SubParent2",
                            "sysList": [{ "name": "Child3", "externalId": "External 3" },
                                { "name": "Child4", "externalId": "External 4" }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        };
```

**TreeTable goes here -**

```
    var inputListBox = new sap.ui.commons.ListBox();
    inputListBox.bindAggregation("items","connList",function(oId,oContext){
        return new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
            key: oContext.getProperty("id"),
            text: oContext.getProperty("name")
        });
    });
    var oTable = new sap.ui.table.TreeTable("treeTable",{
        columns: [
            new sap.ui.table.Column({label: "Tree column", template:new sap.ui.commons.TriStateCheckBox({
                  text: '{name}',
                  selectionState: '{checked}'
              })}),
            new sap.ui.table.Column({label: "Child Column", template: "externalId"}),
            new sap.ui.table.Column({
                label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Connection", design:sap.ui.commons.LabelDesign.Bold}),
                template: new sap.ui.commons.DropdownBox({
                    "association:listBox" : inputListBox
                })
            })
        ],
          selectionMode : sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Multi,
          enableColumnReordering : true,
          expandFirstLevel : true
    });

    var mappingModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({listData:response});
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(mappingModel, "mappingModel");
    oTable.setModel(mappingModel);
    oTable.bindRows("/listData/dataList");
    mappingModel.refresh(true);
    return oTable;
}
```

Comment: why dont you create a new local json from your existing json and bind it to the tree instead of the original? I would Loop through the json, push first and second child into a new json with push-method and then bind it.

Comment: @zyrex ,

I can't create a new local json because I need that values in "connList" for another column.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the properties that will be expanded to a new tree level as binding parameter:

```
 oTable.bindRows({path: "/listData/dataList", parameters: {arrayNames: ["dataList","exList","sysList" ]} });
```

Theres not much to find in the documentation about this except for [one example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#test-resources/sap/ui/core/samples/databinding/DataBindingTreeLarge.html). You can find the source for the example [in the openui5 github](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.32/src/sap.ui.core/test/sap/ui/core/samples/databinding/DataBindingTreeLarge.html#L118).

Comment: Can you provide a source of valid binding parameters? I can not find it in the api reference.

Comment: @nitinp If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.